# Знак доллара в именах переменных C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Заметил, что в именах переменных можно использовать знак доллара. Допустимость этого зависит от компилятора или стандарты предусматривают такую возможность? Если второе верно, то есть ли другие символы, которые допускаются в именах?

Comment: Где это вы такое видели, если не секрет?...

Comment: C: https://ideone.com/s0B2UD
C++: https://ideone.com/90dNqC

Comment: Похоже, просто *расширения* - например, https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/identifiers-cpp?view=vs-2019 - если компилировать с полным соответствием стандарту (`/Za` в VC++) - не сработает.

Comment: В GCC всегда работает. В Clang перестает работать с `-pedantic-errors`. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html

Comment: Но в принципе в `[lex.name]` в стандарте сказано, что можно работать и с определенными диапазонами UCS... Так что, к своему удивлению, только что скомпилировал программу с русскими идентификаторами. Век живи - век учись... Но для переносимости я бы ограничивался перечисленными в том же разделе английскими буквами...

Comment: @Harry, это ещё что... `clang` некоторые эмодзи проглатывает в качестве идентификаторов, например, на таком даже не спотыкается: `enum gender {,};`... где-то человечество свернуло не туда...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а в gcc с -pedantic ?

Comment: @Maggot Работает.